# Link errors with own class functions

Tags: c++, function, hyperlink, linker, linker-errors

I can't find any solutions for this anywhere and it is probably a little error that is so hidden from me.

I've created a couple classes and want to use them in my main class.  Everything compiles good, but when I go to build my project I get Link error dealing with the function calls that  my  class is making

```
Error 11 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
  "public: char __thiscall utility::UtilityClass::convertKeycode(int)" 
   (?convertKeycode@UtilityClass@utility@@QAEDH@Z) referenced in function
   _main C:\Users\Sonny\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GaugePanel\GaugePanel\PointTest.obj GaugePanel
```

basically I make an object of my class i created and call a function.  And my program gives me link errors.

Ive made sure all the include header files are included and everything else I can think of but still i get theses errors . Please help

Sonny.

```
UtilityClass setUpClass = UtilityClass();
displayM = setUpClass.setUpAllegroDisplay();
plugInId1 = setUpClass.setUpUAVConnection();
```

Comment: Well, have you definitely defined `utility::UtilityClass::convertKeycode(int)`?

Comment: Ive included the namespace and header files.

Comment: But have you defined that function?  Not just declared it, but defined it?  (i.e. have you written the body for that function?)

Comment: In my UtilityClass.cpp file I have written the body of the function yes

Comment: Show it please. (Update the *question*; don't link it in a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

It was because in my class when I was defining the function signatures I was not including the class name with the scope operator(I think thats what its called)

so instead of:

long setUpUAVConnection(){}

it had to be like this:

long UtilityClass::setUpUAVConnection(){}

thanks for all your help everyone.

Comment: `::` is the scope *resolution* operator to be exact.